# Does React Router necessarily complicate state management (without Redux)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state, state-management

I'm fairly new to React to trying to wrap my head around routing via React Router while also passing required data to components. I will probably eventually incorporate Redux in my app, but I'm trying to avoid it initially.

It seems like using React Router as opposed to serving individual pages from the server means having to store state data in the `App.js` component since that's where the Router exists.

For example if I'm on `site.com/x` and I want to navigate to `site.com/y` and `/x` looks like this:

```
<div>
  <XOuter >
    <XInner />
  </XOuter>
</div>
```

And App.js looks like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route exact path="/x" component={X} />
  <Route exact path="/y" component={Y} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

... if the GET request is being called from `XInner` and the results will inform the content of `/y`, `XInner` will have to pass the response all the way back to `App.js` to properly render `/y`.

It seems like this could get messy quickly.  Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as bad as you think, for two reasons:

1. If you use [React Router's `<Link>` component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) to create links instead of using `<a>` directly, it will add event handlers that cancel the link's actual navigation and instead use [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) to do the navigation. To the user, they think they're on the new page (the URL bar shows this), but no GET request ever actually happened to load it.
2. React Router's paths are parsed via [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp). This lets you add parameters to the URL and then extract them from the router's props. You can also put data in the query string and then parse it later. This will let you pass state from one page to another without using any top-level React state, with the added benefit of making the browser's history and URL copying automatically work right.

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored in the path instead of `App.js`. Path should be converted to `props` through pure function so the same path is always converted to the same `props`. That's the external state that chooses a `<Route />` and sets its `props`.

Answer (score 0):

Root of your problems lies in this design:

> if the GET request is being called from XInner and the results will inform the content of /y, XInner will have to pass the response all the way back to App.js to properly render /y

Remove the `if the GET request is being called from XInner...` and all your concerns become moot.

Component A should not be responsible for fetching data for Component B. If `/y` needs data, fetch the data in `Y's` [componentdidmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

**Example code showing the concept**

```
  fetchData(){
    fetch(...) // or axios or whatever
     .then(() => {
       this.setState({
         data: 'Hello World'
       })
     })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData()
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.data}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I was referring to data that is shared across different pages, however, I was overthinking this a bit.  I think the best solution is for me to call a synchronous request from `componentDidMount` in whichever page component needs the data.  A synchronous request essentially mirrors the way normal page loading would work.  If I needed to render something (that might change) on all pages, it would make sense to make the request in `componentDidMount` of `App.js`.  Otherwise, requesting it in the page components works.

Comment: CDM (componentDidMount) is not synchronous. And synchronous request is a code smell in itself. But that is not how should be doing thing in react anyway. What you should be doing is dispatch your data fetch in CDM, and in the success handler or callback, update your state (using `this.setState`). See my updated example above.

Comment: Mistake on my part - I'm using `componentWillMount`, but if I do anything asynchronous, the page crashes because it needs the data, which is user-specific, so I can't set an initial state.